# Delete record from database on clicking button using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a method that remove record from database when user press "Delete Button"
The problem is that when I click on that button the Package I want to delete gets removed from the website but when I check database I found the record as it is.

Controller:

```
def deletepackage(user_id,package_id)
  @package=Packages.find(:all, :condition=>{:id => package_id}, 
                                           :condition => {:sender_Id => user_id})
    if (@package!=nil && req.receivedByCarrier==false)
        @package.destroy
    elsif (@package!=nil && req.receivedByCarrier==true)
        @package.destroy
    end
    return;
  end

  def delete
    deletepackage(1,1)
    package.destroy
    redirect_to(:action => 'show') 
  end

  def show
    @create_package=Packages.find(params[:id ])
  end
```

Show.html.erb :

```
 <%=form_for(:package,:url{:action=>'create_packages/delete',
                             :id=>@create_package.id})do |f| %>
   <p>Are you sure you want to delete this package?</p>
   <%= f.submit "Delete" %>
```

Comment: Why don't you use default resource routes? Why do you want to delete your record using form sending `POST` HTTP method instead of `DELETE`?

Comment: Hmmm, i dont get what you mean !

Comment: Just a sidenote, but you really should read a/the [Ruby Styleguide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby). Also, ActiveRecord model names should be singular, not plural (`Package`).

Comment: `deletepackage(1,1)`? shouldn't it be `deletepackage(user.id, params[:id]`)?

Comment: i just wanted to check that it will remove that user.id thats not the problem @UriAgassi  Thanks :)

Comment: I meant that it is hard-coded to `1` - it ignores that parameter you send it, and it will destroy the wrong package (or not find anything...)

Answer (score 4):

**Show.html.erb:**

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', controller: 'your_controller_name', action: 'destroy', id: @package.id, method: :delete %>
```

**Controller:**

```
def show
  @package = Packages.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
  Packages.find_by(id: params[:id], sender_Id: 1).destroy
  redirect_to :index
end
```

You can't redirect to 'show' action from destroy because there are no packages to show (package was destroyed).

**P.S.:**

I think, you need to learn some rails-tutorials, for example, [Michael Hartl's Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).